# Spiky mesh when create mesh from displacement map

Tags: displacement

[image]

Hi guys,I have 2 images with same size and color depth used as displacement map texture, one is very smooth, like the one on the left, the other is very rough, like the one on the right. Any ideas what could've caused this? How do I make the right one smoother. I tried smooth tool and subdivision, doesn't help much

Comment: The left one is too lowpoly to draw the real pattern of the texture. If you decimate the geometry of the right it will be similar.

Comment: If I zoom in closely, I can see that the surface of the left consists of triangles, while the right's consists of spikes. How can I fix that?

Comment: Add a decimate modifier to the right one and decrease the polycount with it.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I figured it out. I used AI to generate the input image on the right and it's still contains some error pixel-wise, therefore the surface is not so smooth. Thanks for the help guys, and sorry for late response